# windows authentication in windows features in iis

Tags: windows-7, iis-7, windows-authentication

I'm having an issue setting up Windows Authentication in IIS 7 on my Windows 7 machine. I know by default this option isn't applied by IIS so you have to tick the Windows Authentication tickbox in Windows Features->Internet Information Services->World Wide Web Services->Security. However, under Security there are only 4 options, which are,
i) Basic Authentication
ii) IP Security
iii) Request Filtering
iv) URL Authorization
Is there any way of getting the Windows Authentication option here? This isn't the only instance where I have noticed this, I've encountered the same problem on another machine with Windows 7 as well.

Thanks,

Pradeep Patel.

Comment: Is the version you installed Professional or above? I think home editions don't provide domain authentification.

Comment: O right I see, I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium. Thanks for the information ebeeb, at least I know the cause of it now!

Answer (score 1):

<s>I think you need to install it first.</s>

> 1. On the taskbar, click Start, and then click Control Panel.
> 2. In Control Panel, click Programs and Features, and then click Turn Windows Features on or off.
> 3. Expand Internet Information Services, then World Wide Web Services, then Security.
> 4. Select Windows Authentication, and then click OK.

[image]

source: [http://www.iis.net/](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication)

This is probably caused by a version of Windows, which doesn't provide domain authentification. This can only be accomplished by **professional or higher** versions of windows.

Answer (score 0):

Because I have the home edition of 7, windows authentication wasn’t available. So enabling or disabling it in my project didn’t really do anything.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/cc754628(v=ws.10).aspx

The only way I could run my app was by clicking on the solution file in Visual Studio to figure out which is my startup project of my solution.
And then I go to the startup project and enable Anonymous Authentication. Worked for me.