# Missing Authentication methods in IIS 7.5 in Windows 7 Home Premium(64-bit)

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, iis

I was trying to test the authorization and authentication parts of my demo MVC Application. But When I logged into IIS I could not find the Windows or as such Forms Authentication Methods listed out there .

[image]

Even the basic Authentication I had to turn on by going into the "Turn Windows Features On or Off " link . But I could not find the Windows Authentication Feature out there.

[image]

What's wrong with this ?

Comment: SO has numerous discussions on non-business editions and win auth  
[Windows 7 SO ref here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683560/windows-authentication-in-windows-features-in-iis)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is purely a vendor product limitation.

Comment: You are using a low end Windows edition designed for home usage. For developers, they have to use high end editions such as Professional so as to see all IIS features available.